# Laravel route with id and name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

I generate URL like this:

```
URL::action('FieldsController@show',['id' => $field->id, 'head' => cleanUrl($field->head)])
```

In my routes I have:

```
Route::get('/field/{head}-{id}', 'FieldsController@show');
```

And it dont work, only when I put ID first and HEAD second like this:

```
Route::get('/field/{id}-{head}', 'FieldsController@show');
```

Anyone have ideas? I need to have ID after HEAD in URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant do routing like

```
{head}-{id}
```

You need to do this:

```
Route::get('/field/{head}/{id}', 'FieldsController@show');
```

Then in your `show()` function you can combine them yourself:

```
function show($head, $id)
{
     $var = $head.'-'.$id;
     // do whatever you want with $var here
}
```

Comment: In your controller. Your route is called `FieldsController@show` - so it is saying it is using a `show()` function?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange why a route can't be done like that?

Comment: @Ravan - You cannot *safely* split variables by `-` in the url. There are issues with trying it that way when Laravel tries to parse the route and determine which text belongs in which variable. Using `/` is only *safe* way to ensure the correct text ends up in the correct variable when parsing. For example - if someone types `/field/this-is-an-example` - which variables go where? It is impossible for Laravel to determine using the original design. But this works: `/field/this-is/an-example`

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like this and it works just fine:

```
Route::get('/blog/{slug}-{article}', [App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class, 'article'])->name('blog.article')->where(['slug' => '[\w]+[^\d]+', 'article' => '[\d]+$']);
```